# Add dist file from npm package to build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yarnpkg

I'm using the [node-poweredup npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-poweredup) in my react based project. I provides a nodejs and a browser version of the library. The browser version is available from the [jsdelivr CDN](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/node-poweredup@latest/dist/browser/poweredup.js) and this is also how I add this library to my react app - I simply include the poweredup.js in a script tag in the index.html.

I can see that the node-poweredup module has a the same file in its `dist/browser` folder (`node_modules/node-poweredup/dist/browser/poweredup.js`). How can I copy this js file to my build directory when running `yarn build` so that I can use this one instead of the one from the CDN?

I have a standard react app created with `create-react-app`.

Comment: Not sure I completely undestand, but have you tried: import poweredup from 'node-pweredup/dist/browser/poweredup.js' ? or just import 'node-poweredup/...rest_of_file' - The second if you don't want to use the actual imported file but just include in your bundle

Comment: Thanks, that brought me on the right track. I'm using typescript and I can do an `import "node-poweredup/dist/browser/poweredup.js"` and then use it like `const poweredUP = new window.PoweredUP.PoweredUP();`.

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing normally. Remove the CDN. react-scripts would package the file during the build.

If the problem still persists, copy the entire directory node_modules/node-poweredup outside of node_modules and do an absolute import.

```
import * from './node-poweredup/${path}'
```

Provide the path from where your modules are being

Or, better yet just download the CDN and use script tag to import in index.js